# How to hash and/or salt passwords in UWP c#?

Tags: c#, hash, uwp

After lots of google searches I really cant seem to find out how to hash passwords in c# UWP, I've tried Bcrypt but that is not available for RT. Any ideas how I can hash my passwords in UWP? This is my first app in UWP so I thought everything would work like in WPF, seems like I was wrong. I have tried the BCRYPT from Nugetstore but nothing will run on UWP.

I just need a simple way to hash and/or salt a string and a simple way to validate the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying all of the above answers ( thanks a lot for helping tho ) i desided to go with MD5 hashing even through i know its a really really weak hashing and have no salt its fine for my need. I hash my passwords in UWP with the following code:

```
private static string ComputeMD5(string str)
     { 
         var alg = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5); 
         IBuffer buff = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(str, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8); 
         var hashed = alg.HashData(buff); 
         var res = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed); 
         return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this approach(`using System.Security.Cryptography`):

- > To store user passwords in the database in a way that they cannot be extracted, the passwords need to be hashed using a one-way hashing algorithm such as SHA1
- > To do so, use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider to create a random salt, append the salt to the password, hash it using SHA1 CryptoServiceProvider class, and store the resulting string in the database along with the salt
- > The benefit provided by using a salted password is making a lookup table assisted dictionary attack against the stored values impractical, provided the salt is large enough

**Sample Code:**

```
  // Create salted password to save in database.
  private byte [] CreateDbPassword(byte[] unsaltedPassword)
  {
     //Create a salt value.
     byte[] saltValue = new byte[saltLength];
     RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
     rng.GetBytes(saltValue);

     return CreateSaltedPassword(saltValue, unsaltedPassword);
  }

  // Create a salted password given the salt value.
  private byte[] CreateSaltedPassword(byte[] saltValue, byte[] unsaltedPassword)
  {
     // Add the salt to the hash.
     byte[] rawSalted  = new byte[unsaltedPassword.Length + saltValue.Length]; 
     unsaltedPassword.CopyTo(rawSalted,0);
     saltValue.CopyTo(rawSalted,unsaltedPassword.Length);

     //Create the salted hash.         
     SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
     byte[] saltedPassword = sha1.ComputeHash(rawSalted);

     // Add the salt value to the salted hash.
     byte[] dbPassword  = new byte[saltedPassword.Length + saltValue.Length];
     saltedPassword.CopyTo(dbPassword,0);
     saltValue.CopyTo(dbPassword,saltedPassword.Length);

     return dbPassword;
  }

     // Compare the hashed password against the stored password.
private bool ComparePasswords(byte[] storedPassword, byte[] hashedPassword)
{
   if (storedPassword == null || hashedPassword == null || hashedPassword.Length != storedPassword.Length - saltLength)
      return false;

   // Get the saved saltValue.
   byte[] saltValue = new byte[saltLength];
   int saltOffset = storedPassword.Length - saltLength;
   for (int i = 0; i < saltLength; i++)
      saltValue[i] = storedPassword[saltOffset + i];

   byte[] saltedPassword = CreateSaltedPassword(saltValue, hashedPassword);

   // Compare the values.
   return CompareByteArray(storedPassword, saltedPassword);
}

// Compare the contents of two byte arrays.
private bool CompareByteArray(byte[] array1, byte[] array2)
{
   if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
      return false;

   int mismatch = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
   {
      mismatch |= array1[i] ^ array2[i];
   }
   return mismatch == 0;
}
```

#### MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288534(v=vs.71).aspx

**UPDATE**
For `UWP` apps you need to use the namespace `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core`:

```
public String SampleDeriveFromPbkdf(
    String strAlgName,
    UInt32 targetSize)
{
    // Open the specified algorithm.
    KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider objKdfProv = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);

    // Create a buffer that contains the secret used during derivation.
    String strSecret = "MyPassword";
    IBuffer buffSecret = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strSecret, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

    // Create a random salt value.
    IBuffer buffSalt = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(32);

    // Specify the number of iterations to be used during derivation.
    UInt32 iterationCount = 10000;

    // Create the derivation parameters.
    KeyDerivationParameters pbkdf2Params = KeyDerivationParameters.BuildForPbkdf2(buffSalt, iterationCount);

    // Create a key from the secret value.
    CryptographicKey keyOriginal = objKdfProv.CreateKey(buffSecret);

    // Derive a key based on the original key and the derivation parameters.
    IBuffer keyDerived = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(
        keyOriginal,
        pbkdf2Params,
        targetSize);

    // Encode the key to a hexadecimal value (for display)
    String strKeyHex = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(keyDerived);

    // Return the encoded string
    return strKeyHex;
}
```

Comment: This seems great but how do i validate the passwords ?

Comment: It might make an attack with a lookup table harder, but with only one iteration, dictionary attack is not going to be difficult at all.

Comment: @SteffenCH functions added to the answer...

Comment: Thanks a alot i will try it after work today and i will make sure to mark it as answer if it worked :)

Comment: This dossent seem to be working for UWP tho, it do not recognize the code, ive tried with Windows.Security.Cryptography and System.Security but UWP do not contain a "System.Security.Cryptograph "

Comment: It's `using System.Security.Cryptography`

Comment: "CryptographicBuffer" is not apart of Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core it dossent seem like any one have figured it out in UWP yet

Comment: It is part of Windows.Security.Cryptography, e.g:
var iBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(value, encoding);

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple library on [GitHub](https://github.com/ilya-git/SimpleHashing.Net) to do just that which is much better than using SHA directly. It uses MS PBKDF2 inside via `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` (no fancy invented home-brew algorithms in there) and is as easy to use as BCrypt.

I have a nuget package as well, but I suppose you'll need to compile it yourself to use with UWP.

Example usage:

```
ISimpleHash simpleHash = new SimpleHash();

// Creating a user hash, hashedPassword can be stored in a database
// hashedPassword contains the number of iterations and salt inside it similar to bcrypt format
string hashedPassword = simpleHash.Compute("Password123");

// Validating user's password by first loading it from database by username
string storedHash = _repository.GetUserPasswordHash(username);
bool isPasswordValid = false;
if (storedHash != null)
{
    isPasswordValid = simpleHash.Verify("Password123", storedHash);
}
```

P.S. I guess I can even compile it to use with UWP target for nuget if it works for you and I figure out how to do that :)

Comment: I get the following error when trying to install it through Nuget http://prntscr.com/d4j0vs im going try to compile it myself, thanks a lot if it worked i will of course make sure to mark it as answer. After trying to install it via Nuget console i get this error http://hastebin.com/etonefotox.py i cant tell tho if its a problem on my site or not.

Comment: I never compiled it for uwp (have not worked with it) and don't know which target to use. But if you can confirm that it works, I can try to update the nuget.

Comment: Sadly this dossent work because " using System.Security.Cryptography; " is not a part of UWP :/

Comment: This MSDN page claims it's part of UWP https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185488.aspx. But other SO question seem to have the same problem.

Comment: It seems there is a special PBKDF2 implementation to UWP. Example here: https://gist.github.com/charlesportwoodii/a571e1a3541b708df18881f086e31002. You can replace rfcderivedbytes with this

Comment: Windows.Security.Cryptography do not contain " Rfc2898DeriveBytes ". The other example you provided me dos not seem to be working either, im running the newest SDK windows 10 Anniversary. I have tried takeing the class you provided and i have replaced " Rfc2898DeriveBytes " with the PBKDF but that just gives lots of errors even tough it uses and recognizes  " using Windows.Security.Cryptography; " and " using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core; "

Comment: Sorry then, it seems not very compatible...

Comment: Sadly thats my realizeation too, very small community, a lot of things missing. Great idea with UWP but very bad in pratice.